# Jfrog Artifactory Access token not working with Local Repository

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to download artifacts from my company's Jfrog Artifactory.
To do so, I have generated an Identity Token, that can be used as password (as per the documentation).
Now, to simplify, I have one Local Repository on Artifactory, and one Virtual Repository (that aggregates that one Local Repository). Will call them Local and Virtual.

I have the following things that do work properly:

- Curl my artifact from Local Repository, using Jfrog's REST API and my Identity Token
- Curl my artifact from Virtual Repository, using Jfrog's REST API and my Identity Token

These two are just to ensure that my token functions properly.
Also working:

- Put Identity Token in `settings.xml` as password for the Virtual Repository, and build my project with maven. Artifact is properly downloaded.
- Same, with encrypted token (through `mvn --encrypt-password`)

Not working:

- Put Identity Token in `settings.xml` as password for the Local Repository, and build my project with maven. Artifact is not downloaded, with error `Could not find artifact ...`
- Same, with encrypted token (through `mvn --encrypt-password`)

Now looking at the Artifactory Access Logs, when it works, I get:
`[ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] virtual:artifact  for client : {X} / {IP Address} [token]`

When it does not, I get:
`[DENIED DOWNLOAD] local:artifact  for client : NA / {IP Address}`

It seems that for Local Repository, it no longer recognizes authentication through Identity Token.

Have I missed something obvious? Is this a (known) bug (that I should report)?

Regards,

PS: Yes, I realize I can use that Virtual Repository and be on my way. I mainly don't want to clutter my list of repositories.

Comment: Did you enable force authentication on the repository configuration level?
I see NA which means that the user might be not authenticated - Artifactory maybe doesn't challenge the client for the token.

Comment: The Virtual repository does force authentication (in its settings), and is the one that works. I can't find a similar option for the Local repository, so I'm guessing it's also enabled. Would make sense.

Comment: can you add what Artifactory version and the relevant artifactory-request.log entries?